# SELECT *,LAST(date_time)

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, aggregate-functions

I'm running a while loop to get the most recent message of each conversation, however I am getting the error

```
[18-Feb-2012 21:14:59] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /path/messages.php on line 44
```

Here is the full loop. It worked before I added ,LAST(date_time) and GROUP BY conversation however I only want to display the latest message in each conversation, not every single message. How can I do this?

```
<?php 
  $current_user = user_info('id',1); //get logged in user id
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, LAST(date_time) 
                          FROM messages 
                         WHERE user_to='$current_user' 
                      ORDER BY date_time DESC 
                         LIMIT 0,5 
                      GROUP BY conversation");
  while($message = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
?>
                <li><strong><?php user_info('first_name',0,$message['user_from']); ?> <?php $sender_last_name = user_info('last_name',0,$message['user_from']); ?></strong><span class="message_time"><?php echo time2str($message['date_time']); ?></span><br />
                <span class="message_description"><?php echo substr($message['content'],0,50); ?></span></li>
                <?php } ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GROUP BY clause goes after the WHERE, before the ORDER BY clause:

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, LAST(date_time) 
                          FROM messages 
                         WHERE user_to='$current_user' 
                      GROUP BY conversation
                      ORDER BY date_time DESC 
                         LIMIT 0,5 ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your query, you seem to have some problem with the ordering of statements.

Take a look at the [MySQL Manual on Select Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

`GROUP BY` statement should come before `ORDER BY` then followed by `LIMIT`. Your ordering in the statement is wrong.

Besides, like what Mike mentioned, you should use `mysql_error()` to see what error is MySQL throwing.